# Replacing outer cursor to inner cursor

Tags: plsql

Good morning/afternoon, i hope i can receive a quick answer to this: 
I have received the question to update the following block:

```
    DECLARE
    v_region_id wf_world_regions.region_id%TYPE;
    CURSOR country_curs
    (p_region_id wf_world_regions.region_id%TYPE) IS
    SELECT country_name, area
    FROM wf_countries
    WHERE region_id = p_region_id
    ORDER BY country_name;
    country_rec country_curs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT region_id INTO v_region_id
    FROM wf_world_regions
    WHERE region_name = 'Central America';
    OPEN country_curs(v_region_id);
    LOOP
        FETCH country_curs INTO country_rec;
        EXIT WHEN country_curs%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (country_rec.country_name ||
        ' ' || country_rec.area);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE country_curs;
END;
```

To the following: 
Modify the code,  move all cursor references into the nested block. The Declarations of v_region_id and the SELECT still has to be handled by the outer block.

I am on a deadlock here, because I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately for you SO is not someone-do-my-homework resource. If you have no idea about PL/SQL, you should start reading appropriate documentation or tutorials and try to solve it. If you face some problems doing that then post your code that doesn't work and somebody will help to correct it. At least show your effort.

Comment: I will agree with @YaroslavShabalin on this one.  I don't mind helping, but it's gotta be more than a cut-and-paste operation from whomever has assigned you this chunk of code.  Demonstrate what you understand... what you don't... and what you think you need to know to keep moving on this one.

Answer (score 1):

## My Homework Assignment  :)

*Learn some programming through dissecting a chunk of Oracle PL/SQL code.*

Hang around and have a read through this guide, it may prove a useful learning exercise.  You'll just have to apply a little mental energy to keep up...

### Task One:  Identify the Inner and Outer PL/SQL Block

What is a PL/SQL Block of Code?  The OP is an example of a `Anonymous PL/SQL Block`.  This means it does not live in the database once it has been executed.

To split apart the code sample, consider the components of [a typical Oracle PL/SQL Block](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1RSsDL-4j14oWP7Qw-D_fQPhSsBy3rppjXfJMrR5WQFI/edit?usp=sharing).  The link is to a diagram inspired by a favorite reference by Steven Feuerstein and Bill Pribyl (some of you out there might still have a print version beside you right now...)

[image: Oracle PL/SQL Programming Book]

> If you can read the cover, it says:  "Covers Oracle 8"... many of the principles from this book are 100% relevant even with today's newer releases of the Oracle database...

### Task Two:  What is a Cursor, and what does it look like?

A [PL/SQL Cursor](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/declare.php) has the term `CURSOR` followed by some SQL query block beginning with `SELECT ... FROM... etc.`

Try rearranging the code until you can identify discrete, functional parts and instructions that can be grouped together... take a second look at the original, compressed block of code from above:

[image: Reformatted PL/SQL Code Block]

Can you find the cursor in the code?

**An Example of an INNER and OUTER PL/SQL Block**

After circling around the actual assignment you were originally presented, here's a good visual tie-in to show the concept that was intended by my efforts (and ultimately the assignment tied to the OP)

IF a PL/SQL block is defined by discrete parts with keywords such as `DECLARE`, `BEGIN`, `EXCEPTION`, and `END`, the next step is to show how you can put Blocks WITHIN Blocks.:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR some_cur IS ...;

BEGIN

        DECLARE
           my_results VARCHAR2(10);

        BEGIN

              DECLARE
                  v_output  number;
              BEGIN
                  ...
              END;

         END;
 END;
```

This is what we're getting at when we talk about `INNER` and `OUTER` program components.  With a little research or just plain experimentation, you will see that

### Task Three:  Try to Ignore What Isn't Relevant to the Exercise

There are some other things that you might think you need to know to finish this assignment.  Some distractions that I noticed are things like the fancier variable declaration notation:

```
v_region_id wf_world_regions.region_id%TYPE;

uses the preferred format:

<variable name>  <table name>.<column name>%TYPE;
```

This is actually a very good practice, so maybe you can remember this for the future.  The variable called `v_region_id` was created to handle data for comparison to values contained in the table: `wf_world_regions` and with the column named `region_id`.  What data type do you need to accept?  It doesn't matter and you don't need to know.  The variable was designed to adopt whatever type was set for that table's attribute.

Some beginning developers (and some of us old-timers) remember declaring data types explicitly and wildly over-guessing and padding our variable sizes to accommodate for the "unknown".

### Task Four:  Identify the Request... and its Intent

Now that you have the background on the basics of PL/SQL code blocks, consider what has been asked.

> *Modify the code, move all cursor references into the nested block. The Declarations of v_region_id and the SELECT still has to be handled by the outer block.*

If for example your code sample was much, much larger think about what would happen if any of these functional units of code (such as cursors and cursor processing loops) were to fail for any reason.  This is the purpose of having an `EXCEPTION` block.

It's also a valid strategy to `NEST` your smaller program units and commands in their own defined PL/SQL program blocks.  The following diagram is for EXCEPTION handling, but it also describes the flow of execution through nested code blocks.

[image: Exception Block Handling with Nested PLSQL Code Blocks]

... Well, that's about it for the lesson.  Knowing what you do now, how would you approach the request to refactor this code?

### Some Hints and Tips to Try

- **Errors Are Your Exceptional Friends:**  Try introducing some errors of your own.  Make the code do things you know it won't want to.  If you introduce an `EXCEPTION` block, with a little ingenuity, you can get the code to give you clues about how the database interpreted and executed different parts of your code.
- **DBMS OUT-what?**  If you haven't encountered this command before, consider using it a lot in your code when you are first learning how your samples work.  It is like the `PRINT` command in other languages, which means the database puts the command out to your screen when it is executed.  It's good for setting up markers and also a way of following the execution progress through your code.

  That statement in PL/SQL is:

  `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Text Output Here');`

  The text output can be any string value or string-typed variable.

> Hopefully this will give you a head-start on what you seek.  Apologies for any mis-informed assumptions made about the nature or reason for this post... there are a lot of people here who like to help, but also have a distaste for providing "easy answers" without any evidence of some initial effort.

This post opens up a useful discussion on the basics of PL/SQL programming so I'm sure it will prove to be a help for others who may read this as well.  Good luck!